# Collect all of the successes and failures of a sequence of ZIOs together?

Tags: scala, zio

I have a bunch of `IO`s, all of which may have either succeeded or failed:

```
val result: Seq[IO[MyFailure, MySuccess]] = ...
```

I need to summarize the results such that I can examine all the failures and all the successes *together*:

```
case class MySummary(failures: Seq[MyFailure], successes: Seq[MySuccess])
def makeSummary(results: Seq[IO[MyFailure, MySuccess]]): UIO[MySummary] = ???
```

At first this seemed quite similar to `foreach`, but upon closer inspection I see that that doesn't help here. For `Future` I'd normally use `sequence`, and for `Seq[Either[A,B]]` I could use `partitionMap`. What is the equivalent method in ZIO named?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't examine all failures with `Future.sequence`, you will only get back the first failure if there is any.

The ZIO equivalent for `Future.sequence` would be `ZIO.collectAll` which is pretty much equivalent to `ZIO.foreach(result)(identity)`.

If you really need to accumulate all errors then you should probably use `ZIO.validate` and for partitioning there's also `ZIO.partition`.

Some code for comparison:

```scala
  val result: Seq[IO[MyFailure, MySuccess]] = ???

  val withCollectAll: IO[MyFailure, Seq[MySuccess]] = ZIO.collectAll(result)
  val withForeach: IO[MyFailure, Seq[MySuccess]] = ZIO.foreach(result)(identity)
  val withValidate: IO[::[MyFailure], Seq[MySuccess]] = ZIO.validate(result)(identity) //`::` just means that the list cannot be empty
  val withPartition: UIO[(Iterable[MyFailure], Iterable[MySuccess])] = ZIO.partition(result)(identity)
```

Code for `makeSummary` with `ZIO.partition`:

```scala
  def makeSummary(results: Seq[IO[MyFailure, MySuccess]]): UIO[MySummary] =
    ZIO.partition(results)(identity).map { case (f, s) => MySummary(f.toSeq, s.toSeq) }
```

Comment: Ah you are indeed correct that `Future.sequence` is not precisely analagous to what I'm asking for with `makeSummary`, but `validate` is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, notable item of documentation on `validate` reads "_This combinator is lossy meaning that if there are errors all successes will be lost. To retain all information please use partition._". So in fact the method I need is probably actually `partition`.

Comment: @CoryKlein yeah I just saw that what you actually wanted was to partition. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm not familiar with ZIO, there might be a built-in way to achieve the same.*

I would go with something like the following:

```scala
def makeSummary(results: Seq[IO[MyFailure, MySuccess]]): UIO[MySummary] = {
  results.foldLeft(ZIO.succeed(MySummary(Seq(), Seq()))) { (acc, io) =>
    acc.flatMap { summary => 
      io.fold(
        err => summary.copy(failures = summary.failures :+ err),
        suc => summary.copy(successes = summary.succcesses :+ suc)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoting because this technically is a correct implementation of my `makeSummary` method. Thank you!